# Problem rotating an object on its local orientation

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, rotation, trigonometry, quaternions

Hello i am new in the forum! I hope i am in the right section! Im trying to rotate a camera (that rapresent the player POV) using the mouse delta and im rotating the camera in local coordinates not world coordinates and i want avoid gimbal lock effect. I read somewhere on the internet that for that purpose i have to use quaternions, and i read how to do that. The problem is that axis rotations works well moving in local orientation but one of the axis is losing its local orientation and it rotate following the world coordinates orientation. I will post the code and i hope someone can help me and telling me where im doing things wrong. Thanks!

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

[Header("Camera")]
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;
[SerializeField] private Vector2 _xMinMaxRotation = new Vector2(-90, 90);
[SerializeField] private Vector2 _yMinMaxRotation = new Vector2(-90, 90);
[SerializeField] private float _mouseXSensistivity = 1;
[SerializeField] private float _mouseYSensistivity = 1;
[SerializeField] private float _mouseZSensistivity = 1;
[SerializeField] private float _xStartRotation = 0;
[SerializeField] private float _yStartRotation = 0;
private Vector2 _mouseDelta;
private float _rotY, _rotX, _rotZ;

//public GameObject head;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() {
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    _mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
    MoveCamera();
}


private void MoveCamera() {
    _rotX += _mouseDelta.x * _mouseXSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 100;
    _rotX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotX, _xMinMaxRotation.x, _xMinMaxRotation.y);
    _rotY += _mouseDelta.y * _mouseYSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 100;
    _rotY = Mathf.Clamp(_rotY, _yMinMaxRotation.x, _yMinMaxRotation.y);

    //Calculation for RotZ
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)) {
        _rotZ += +_mouseZSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
        if (_rotZ > 25) _rotZ = 25;
    }
    else {
        if (_rotZ > 0) {
            _rotZ -= 2 * _mouseZSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
            if (_rotZ < 0) _rotZ = 0;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
        _rotZ += -_mouseZSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
        if (_rotZ < -25) _rotZ = -25;
    }
    else {
        if (_rotZ < 0) {
            _rotZ -= 2 * -_mouseZSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
            if (_rotZ > 0) _rotZ = 0;
        }
    }

    Quaternion currentRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    currentRotation = currentRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(_rotX, transform.up);
    currentRotation = currentRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(-_rotY, transform.right);
    currentRotation = currentRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(_rotZ, transform.forward);
    _camera.transform.localRotation = currentRotation;

    //head.transform.position = _camera.transform.position;
    //head.transform.rotation = _camera.transform.rotation;
}
```

The last part with quaternions is where im trying to calculate angles in order to properly rotate in local coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to use quaternions at all.

You can use transform.EulerAngles instead of the transform.rotation or transform.localEulerAngles instead of transform.LocalRotation.

I messed up the capitalization I’m sure.

Say you wanted to rotate the camera 10 degrees along the local x axis. That would look something like

```
transform.localEulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles.Add(10,0,0);
```

That’s it as far as I know. If you wanna read more about this,
[transfrom.localEulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html)

If your question was completely different, let me know and I can change or remove my answer.

Comment: Hello mate! My question is not far. The problem persist. If for example i pass my angles values (that in my case are mousedelta.Y for the X axis, mousedelta.X for Y axis and the Q or E Keys for the Z value) like this:                         _camera.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-_rotY, _rotX, _rotZ);                      the X and the Z axis will follow the object orientation so it's fine, because is what i want but the Y axis will rotate in the Y world coordinates orientation. It's reall werid behaviour i think.

Comment: @VincentMazzarella This is probably a problem with your specific code. Unity's localEulerAngles do not have this issue you are describing. You will need to show code and your workspace or I cannot help you.

Comment: My code is on the decscription above!